# Simple utility to unhide mouse cursor in objective c console app

Tags: objective-c, console-application, exc-bad-access, nscursor

I'm trying to create a simple console app to unhide the cursor because a program I use has a bug and hides the cursor intermittently (Would rather write a quick util than wait for the bug to be fixed).  I have added the AppKit framework and written the following simple console app (main.m):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/NSCursor.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [NSCursor unhide];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the `[NSCursor unhide]` line.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running this on Lion with XCode 4.3.2

I am also open to doing this with AppleScript, but I haven't been able to accomplish it there either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't going to work. Cursor objects are managed and owned by each application. You can't affect another application's cursor (without code injection).

You get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because your program here doesn't actually have a cursor. One would be created during the usual GUI app start-up process, i.e., in `NSApplicationMain()`, if you had created a "Cocoa Application", but you would still only be able to affect your own application's cursor.

AppleScript seems like it would have a better chance of success, since it lets you execute some code that directly affects other apps, but I'm not at all sure that it has functionality to manage the cursor like this -- it seems a little too low-level for AS.

Comment: So, that explains why I can get the cursor back by switching to another app and back.  The troublesome app is, itself, a console executable.  It will cause the cursor to disappear in various intermittent apps, so maybe it's doing it's own code injection of the frontmost app to perform that.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I should mention that the mouse cursor hiding is a feature of the executable.  It just has a hard time unhiding the cursor sometimes per a bug.

Comment: I would guess it's doing some injection, then, yes. That's outside my area of expertise, unfortunately; I have no idea how you would interfere with that. Just out of curiousity, do you mind naming the utility?

Comment: This is an old version of synergyc. It works in all other respects (unfortunately, the newer versions do not), except the cursor issue.  Maybe I can dig into the code and recompile it, but I was hoping to avoid that for small amount that I use it.